# How to detect current state within directive

Tags: angular-ui

I'm using AngularUI's routing and I'd like to do a `ng-class="{active: current.state}"` but I'm unsure how to exactly detect the current state in a directive like this.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Also you can use **ui-sref-active** directive:

```
<ul>
  <li ui-sref-active="active" class="item">
    <a href ui-sref="app.user({user: 'bilbobaggins'})">@bilbobaggins</a>
  </li>
  <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

Or filters:
`"stateName" | isState` & `"stateName" | includedByState`

Answer (score 146):

**Update:**

This answer was for a much older release of Ui-Router. For the more recent releases (0.2.5+), please use the helper directive `ui-sref-active`. Details [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active).

---

**Original Answer:**

Include the $state service in your controller. You can assign this service to a property on your scope.

An example:

```
$scope.$state = $state;
```

Then to get the current state in your templates:

```
$state.current.name
```

To check if a state is current active:

```
$state.includes('stateName');
```

This method returns true if the state is included, even if it's part of a nested state. If you were at a nested state, `user.details`, and you checked for `$state.includes('user')`, it'd return true.

In your class example, you'd do something like this:

```
ng-class="{active: $state.includes('stateName')}"
```

Comment: What about for states that have parameters?

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stateincludesstatename--params

Answer (score 25):

If you are using ui-router, try $state.is();

You can use it like so:

`$state.is('stateName');`

Per the [documentation:](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.3.1/index.html#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_is)

> $state.is ... similar to $state.includes, but only checks for the full state name.

Answer (score 1):

The use of **ui-sref-active** directive that worked for me was:

```
<li ui-sref-active="{'active': 'admin'}">
    <a ui-sref="admin.users">Administration Panel</a>
</li>
```

as found [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1431) under the comment labeled "tgrant59 commented on May 31, 2016".

I am using angular-ui-router v0.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Check out angular-ui, specifically, route checking:
http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/

Comment: I'm trying to check the current state, not necessarily the route