# Angular.js add class to element when in some page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to add the class `post` to my div `#wrap` when i'm on the page `/post`. That's what I have:

$routeProvider

```
when('/post', {
    templateUrl : 'views/post.php',
    controller  : 'postCtrl'
})
```

Controller

```
carolvaladares.controller('postCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.post = true;
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrap" ng-class="{true: 'post'}[post]">
```

When on `/post`, `$scope.post` is `true`. If the `$scope.post` is `true`, add the class `post` to `#wrap`

The thing is that when I go to `/post`, It does not read the `$scope.post` unless I use `ng-controller="postCtrl"` manually.

Thanks in advance.

**-- EDITED --**

The `$scope.post` returns `true` when I use `{{post}}` on `/post`. Still I can't work with `ng-class`.

**-- EDITED --**

The problem still happening because the `#wrap` is out of my `ng-view`. So I guess what I'm trying to do, the way I'm trying to do won't be possible.

Comment: Does your controller load when you navigate to /post and i hope you are using ng-view

Comment: Yes. I'm using ng-view, and the controller loads when I navigate to /post. I tested it using a simple $scope.message and {{message}} to confirm it.

Comment: Did my answer work... do you get any console error message?

Comment: It is not clear where #wrap is placed in html, please check scopes, may be #wrap is outside controller's scope. [Check example](http://plnkr.co/edit/6lFsKklLampT4Tf767YE)

Comment: @Artem Yeah man, it worked this way here too. But I'm trying to understand how could I affect some element out of my ng-view without specifying the controller manually. Because if I specify the controller, It would affect every page on my application.

Comment: @MatheusSouza Could you look at [How to detect current state within directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215656/how-to-detect-current-state-within-directive)

Comment: @Artem Thanks for the help. I'll look at it and try to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your HTML:

```
<div id="wrap" ng-class="{ className: post === true }">
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`<div id="wrap" ng-class="{'post': post}">`

Also don't forget to add the ng-controller

Comment: It works if I use `ng-controller="postCtrl"` manually on `#wrap`. That way, all the other pages would also add the class `post`.

Answer (score 0):

ng-class works like this:

`ng-class="{'classNameToApply': angularExpression}"`

The 'classNameToApply' will be applied when the `angularExpression` evaluates to something truthy.

So in your case, to apply the class of 'post', you would do 
`<div id="wrap" ng-class="{'post': post}">`

Comment: It works if I use `ng-controller="postCtrl"` manually on `#wrap`. That way, all the other pages would also add the class `post`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="wrap" ng-class="{true: 'post'}[post]">
```

The statement you have given for `ng-class` should work, could you change your `post` variable to something else to check if its working like below:

```
<div id="wrap" ng-class="{true: 'post'}[someValue]">
```

Apart from this, there is other solutions below which you can try:

**Sol1:**

```
<div id="wrap" ng-class="{'post': post}">
```

**Sol2**

```
<div id="wrap" ng-class="post ? 'post' : 'somethingelse' }">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try something like this:

```
when('/post', {
    templateUrl : 'views/post.php',
    controller  : 'postCtrl',
    activetab: 'post'
})
```

and add:

`<div id="wrap" ng-class="{post: $route.current.activetab == 'post'}"">`